# Power BI Desktop vs Web Client

Tags: powerbi

What is the difference between the Power BI desktop client and web client. Both seem to have the same features. What can the desktop client do that the web client cannot do?

Comment: One of the reason I rely on Desktop is, if by mistake I delete a web client report/dashboard,  I still have a pbix as a backup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to be exhaustive since there are a ton of features in both experiences. The Power BI Desktop is intended as a tool for Analysts to work with data.  It includes data load, mashup, data modeling, and reporting capabilities.  You can create models with relationships, calculated columns and DAX measures. You can create crazy transforms to manipulate the data to shape it into as good shape or merge data from multiple sources into a single data model. The web version of reports really focuses on the reporting piece. If someone else is doing all the data modeling for you, then the web reporting UI is pretty comprehensive.  If you need to do the data modeling yourself, then Desktop is the way to go.  Desktop does have the added benefit of a file you can save or archive.  It doesn't support the direct query sources or push data sets like the web report feature.  So there are at least some limitations.  Which you use really depends on the types of problems you're trying to overcome.