# Getting Live Data from Power BI Desktop and Web Client?

Tags: powerbi, http-live-streaming, dynatrace

I am trying to connect to Dynatrace through its API in Power BI. There is a lot of documentation within [Dynatrace](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/environment-api/metric-v2/) and [Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming) sites, but it isn't clear which is better suited to handle Live data. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757523/power-bi-desktop-vs-web-client) seemed on the same topic but also didn't address the subject of live data. Is the Power BI application you use arbitrary in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, **PBI Desktop**.

Power BI Web Client is primarily for sharing, accessing, and editing previous Charts, Dashboards, Etc. There are ways to connect using the Online version, but the tool is a little less clunky on the Desktop even though the Online version seems streamlined.

Power BI Desktop can push Dash's, Reports, and other visualized Data to the Web Client. Power BI Desktop is the best for in-house access to Dynatrace's API for a live feed of data.